# SQL XML path conversion results error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by, common-table-expression, for-xml-path

Actually I m begineer to SQL XML path as so making me professional, Got a scenario... 
I have a CTE Function That results as

```
Data    Chars   NumberOfOccurance
12  1   1 appears (1 ) times
12  2   2 appears (1 ) times
xx  x   x appears (2 ) times
```

and CTE function is :

```
  ;with cte as
    (
        select Data , SUBSTRING(Data,1,1) as Chars,1 as startpos from @t
        union all
        select Data, SUBSTRING(Data, startpos+1,1) as char,startpos+1 from cte where startpos+1<=LEN(data)
    )
    select Data,Chars,Cast(Chars as varchar(1)) + ' appears (' + cast(COUNT(*) as varchar(5))+  ' ) times' as 'NumberOfOccurance' from cte 
    group by data, chars
```

Actually I just want to make my answer into this :

```
data    Number_of_occurances
12  1 appears (1) times 2 appears (1) times
xx  x appears (2) times
```

I have tries this :

```
; With Ctea as 
(
select Data , SUBSTRING(Data,1,1) as Chars,1 as startpos from @t
    union all
    select Data, SUBSTRING(Data, startpos+1,1) as char,startpos+1 from ctea where startpos+1<=LEN(data)
)
select Data,Chars,REPLACE((SELECT (Cast(Chars as varchar(1)) + ' appears (' + cast(COUNT(*) as varchar(5))+ ' ) times') AS [data()] FROM Ctea t2 WHERE t2.Data = t1.data FOR XML PATH('')), ' ', ' ;') As Number_of_occurances  from ctea as t1
group by t1.data, t1.Chars
```

It says :

```
Column 'Ctea.Chars' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

when I use temp table and getting my exact answer , but cant do it CTE

Can anyone make my result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FOR XML PATH` like this for concatenation

```
  ;with cte as
    (
        select Data , SUBSTRING(Data,1,1) as Chars,1 as startpos from @t
        union all
        select Data, SUBSTRING(Data, startpos+1,1) as char,startpos+1 from cte where startpos+1<=LEN(data)
    ), CTE2 AS
    (
    select Data,Chars,Cast(Chars as varchar(1)) + ' appears (' + cast(COUNT(*) as varchar(5))+  ' ) times' as 'NumberOfOccurance' from cte 
    group by data, chars
    )
    SELECT Data,(SELECT NumberOfOccurance + ' ' FROM CTE2 c2 WHERE c2.Data = C1.Data FOR XML PATH(''),type).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') as Number_of_occurances 
    FROM CTE2 C1
    GROUP BY Data
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem has nothing to do with your CTE. It actually lies in the following subquery:

```
SELECT (Cast(Chars as varchar(1)) + 
    ' appears (' + 
    cast(COUNT(*) as varchar(5)) + 
    ' ) times') AS [data()] 
FROM Ctea t2 
WHERE t2.Data = t1.data 
FOR XML PATH('')
```

Note how you are using the aggregate `COUNT(*)` here as well as the column `Chars`. You need to group by at least `Chars` here:

```
SELECT (Cast(Chars as varchar(1)) + 
    ' appears (' + 
    cast(COUNT(*) as varchar(5)) + 
    ' ) times') AS [data()] 
FROM Ctea t2 
WHERE t2.Data = t1.data 
GROUP BY t2.Chars
FOR XML PATH('')
```

Furthermore, you do *not* want to select or group by `t1.Chars` in the outer query because it will result in one row per value of Chars:

```
data  chars   Number_of_occurances
12    1       1 appears (1) times 2 appears (1) times
12    2       1 appears (1) times 2 appears (1) times
xx    x       x appears (2) times
```

Finally you should most likely be using the [`STUFF` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx), and not `REPLACE`, as you are trying to create a space-delimited list ("*1 appears (1) times 2 appears (1) times*"), not replace all space characters with a space and a semicolon ("*1 ;appears ;(1) ;times ;2 ;appears ;(1) ;times*").

Therefore your final query should be:

```
; With Ctea as 
(
    select Data , SUBSTRING(Data,1,1) as Chars,1 as startpos from @t
    union all
    select Data, SUBSTRING(Data, startpos+1,1) as char,startpos+1 from ctea 
    where startpos+1<=LEN(data)
)
select Data,
    STUFF((SELECT cast(' ' as varchar(max)) + (Cast(Chars as varchar(1)) + ' appears (' + cast(COUNT(*) as varchar(5))+ ' ) times') AS [data()] 
           FROM Ctea t2 
           WHERE t2.Data = t1.data 
           GROUP BY t2.Chars 
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') As Number_of_occurances  
from ctea as t1
group by t1.data
```